# Could a determinstic primality test specialized to this form of prime exist?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it possible there could be an "efficient" deterministic primality test for prime numbers of the form

$$(2^n + 1)^2 - 2$$

or

$$(2^n - 1)^2 - 2$$

in the same vein as the Lucas-Lehmer test for Mersenne numbers ($2^n - 1$) and Proth's theorem ($k 2^n + 1$)?